# How to make servlet call in select box onclick

Tags: javascript, oracle, jsp, servlets, drop-down-menu

How to make servlet call from select box?

I have a select box in my jsp page and each and every selection i have to call servlet and display the content in same jsp page.

example code:

```
<select>
  <option value="spain">spain</option>
  <option value="france">France</option>
  <option value="italy">Italy</option>
  <option value="germany">Germany</option>
</select>
```

Onclick option one to show the country details of spain. same as each and every option.
So how to work with javascript / jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question this what you have to do,

Javascript:

```
function getValue(val){
   document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = val;
}
```

html:

```
<select onchange="getValue(this.value)">
  <option value="spain">spain</option>
  <option value="france">France</option>
  <option value="italy">Italy</option>
  <option value="germany">Germany</option>
</select>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample code

```
<select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Chocolate</option>
    <option selected="selected">Candy</option>

    <option>Taffy</option>
    <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
    <option>Fudge</option>
    <option>Cookie</option>

  </select>
  <div></div>
<script>
    $("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          $("div").text(str);
        })
        .change();
</script>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.
You can also refer it here http://api.jquery.com/change/

Since you also want to call your servlet then you must make an ajax call from inside your code by using the JQuery ajax methods something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,//URL of the servlet controller as in which would invoke it
  data: data,//Data you want to attach to your URL
  success: success,//The anonymous function which will be called on success
  dataType: dataType//The anonymous function which will be called on failure
});
```